# Copiar directorios que la ruta está en un txt usando python

Tags: python

Hola buenas estoy en medio de un proyecto el cual me dan un archivo de texto con los nombres de unas carpetas que tengo que copiar a una ubicación y estoy obteniendo el siguiente error:

```
OSError: [WinError 123] El nombre de archivo, el nombre de directorio o la sintaxis de la etiqueta del volumen no son correctos: 'E:\\Test\\a\n'
```

A continuación les muestro el código:

```
import os
import shutil as clipboard

#lugar donde esta el archivo que contiene lo que vas a copiar
ruta = "E:/Test 2"
nombre_archivo = "copiar.txt"
ruta_archivo = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(ruta, nombre_archivo))

#lugar donde estan las carpetas a copiar
ruta_pqt = os.path.abspath("E:/Test")

#lugar donde vas a pegar los archivos
dst = os.path.abspath("E:/Test 2/test 3")
#para llevar la cuenta cuentas carpetas se copiaron
copia = 0


with open(ruta_archivo,'r') as file: #abriendo el archivo 
    for line in file: #un for para obtener las carpetas a copiar
        src = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(ruta_pqt, line)) #para obtener la ruta completa
        print(f"copiando ..{src}")
        clipboard.copytree(src, dst)
        print(f"{src} copiado con exito")
        copia += 1

print(f"{copia} con exito")
```

Comment: De acuerdo a tu planteamiento sobre el mensaje de error, lo único que hay que hacer es quitar el carácter de fin de linea que se lee desde el archivo con las carpetas a copiar.  `src = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(ruta_pqt, line.rstrip('\n'))) #para obtener la ruta completa, quitar el salto de linea`

Comment: muchas gracias hoy llegue a esa misma conclusión

Answer (score 0):

esta es la solución que le di espero les sea de ayuda

```
import os
import shutil as clipboard

#lugar donde esta el archivo que contiene lo que vas a copiar
ruta = "E:/Test 2"
nombre_archivo = "copiar.txt"
ruta_archivo = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(ruta, nombre_archivo))

#lugar donde estan las carpetas a copiar
ruta_pqt = os.path.abspath("E:/Test")

#lugar donde vas a pegar los archivos
dst = os.path.abspath("E:/Test 2/test 3")
#para llevar la cuenta cuentas carpetas se copiaron
copia = 0
#para poner las lineas del archivo en una lista
copiar = []

with open(ruta_archivo,'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        copiar.append(line)#leer el archivo y guardarlo en lista

for item in copiar:
    copiar2.append(item.rstrip())#elimina los saltos de linea
        
for folder in copiar2:#obtener las carpetas del origen
    if folder in os.listdir(ruta_pqt):#comprobar que la carpeta del origen esta entre las que hay que copiar
        src1 = os.path.join(ruta_pqt, folder)#hago la ruta de la carpeta a copiar
        dst1 = os.path.join(dst, folder)#hago la ruta donde pegar        
        try:
            print(f"copiando {src1}")#muestro que archivo se va a copiar
            clipboard.copytree(src1, dst1)#copia la estructura completa de la carpeta
            copia += 1#incremento el contador de los archivos copiados
        except Exception:
            print(f"no se pudo copiar {src1}")#si falla algo no explota
    else:
        print(f"no hay ningun directorio con el nombre-->{folder}")

print(f"{copia} con exito")#dice cuantos archivos se copiaron con éxito
```

Comment: Acepta tu propia respuesta para dar por cerrada esta pregunta